# Argument expects double but I need floats?

Tags: c, int, double, nan

I'm writing a quadratic equation root solver for class. I either get %f expects argument type double but arguments 2 and 3 have type float on lines 45 and 51, or I get -nan and-inf as an answer when I get it to compile. I can't figure out any other way to get it to work. I cannot use doubles on this. Only floats and ints with the sub programs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void solve_linear(int, int);
void solve_quad(int, int, int);
void solve_real(int,int, int);
void solve_complex(int, int, int);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    int a, b, c;

    if (argc==4) {
        sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &a);
        sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &b);
        sscanf(argv[3], "%d", &c);
        if (a=0){
            if (b=0){
              printf("Error. A and B cannot both be 0\n");
            }
            else solve_linear(b, c);
        }
        else solve_quad(a,b,c);
    }
    else printf("Error. Must enter 3 numbers on command line.\n");
}

void solve_linear(b, c){
    float root;
    root=(float)-c/b;
    printf("%f\n", root);
}

void solve_quad(a, b, c){
    if(b*b-4*a*c<0){
        solve_complex(a,b,c);
    }
    else{
        solve_real(a, b, c);
    }
}
void solve_real(a, b, c){
      float x1, x2;
      x1=(-b+sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a);
      x2=(-b-sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a);
      printf("%f, %f\n", &x1, &x2);
}
void solve_complex(a, b, c){
    float x_real, x_img;
    x_real=-b/(2.0*a);
    x_img=(sqrt(abs(b*b-4*a*c)))/(2*a);
    printf("%f + %fi\n", &x_real, &x_img);
}
```

Comment: `if (a=0){` so 'a' is always zero and divide to a, it's infinity

Comment: `if (a=0)` is always going to return true, what you should be doing is 
`if (a == 0)`. 

Similarly `if (b == 0)`

Comment: Thank you for noticing that. I'm still having trouble with the floats however.

Comment: Using `void solve_quad(a, b, c){ … }` is really old-fashioned code and you should not be writing such code now.  It was bad style in 1989; it is appalling that you're not using compiler options that prevent it being acceptable.  Use the proper prototype notation: `void solve_quad(int a, int b, int c){ … }`.

Comment: Your problem is passing pointers to `printf()` when you should be passing `double` values.  You have: `printf("%f + %fi\n", &x_real, &x_img);` — you need `printf("%f + %fi\n", x_real, x_img);`.  I suppose you are confused between `scanf()` where you need pointers and `"%lf"` to read `double` values, and `printf()` where you need values and `"%f"` is sufficient (though `"%lf"` also works with C99 or later libraries).

Comment: Any particular reason to use float rather  than making everything double?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you call printf, all float arguments are automatically converted to double. You cannot prevent this.

Enable your compiler's warnings, they will tell you that printf expects direct values instead of pointers, so the code should be `printf("%f +%f = %f\n", a, b, a + b);`.

This is the difference: scanf needs pointers (since it *writes* to the variables), pintf only needs the values themselves (so no need for pointers).